# register_shutdown_function and databases problem !

Tags: php, database

Greetings Overflowers,

What is wrong with this PHP code:

```
<?php
define("DB_FILE", "sqlite:database.sql");
define("QUERY", "INSERT INTO Log VALUES (123)");
define("TIME_OUT", "60000");

function track() {
 $db = new PDO(DB_FILE);
 $db->exec(QUERY);

 echo "OK!";
}

register_shutdown_function("track");

// sleep(TIME_OUT);
?>
```

Although "OK!" is printed when script is shutdown, nothing is really inserted into the database table. I tried calling track() directly and it did insert. Can not I do databases inside shutdown functions ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should check if your query ran OK before outputting the *OK!* message. Use [PDO::errorInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) to see what (if anything) went wrong.

Comment: Might I add to also check that the PDO object was actually created / connection succeeded.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, the path to the database file was the problem :)